# Jmeter aggregate certain response values from json to use in next request

Tags: json, jmeter

I have the following response coming from a request

```
[
{
    "id": 3767,
    "sellerName": "abc",
    "siteActivity": [
        {
            "siteId": -1,
            "siteName": "example.com",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "categoryId": 79654,
                    "parentId": null,
                    "name": "Photo &amp; Picture Frames",
                    "siteName": null,
                    "channelType": null
                },
                {
                    "categoryId": 114397,
                    "parentId": null,
                    "name": "Chests of Drawers",
                    "siteName": null,
                    "channelType": null
                },
                {
                    "categoryId": 11707,
                    "parentId": null,
                    "name": "Jewellery Boxes",
                    "siteName": null,
                    "channelType": null
                },
                {
                    "categoryId": 45505,
                    "parentId": null,
                    "name": "Serving Trays",
                    "siteName": null,
                    "channelType": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 118156,
    "sellerName": "xyz",
    "siteActivity": [
        {
            "categoryId": 45505,
            "parentId": null,
            "name": "Serving Trays",
            "siteName": null,
            "channelType": null
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Now, I need to extract "id" values and "categoryId" values and send them as list in the next request body.

Currently, I am using JSON Path Extractor with the expression

```
    $.[*].id
```

to get my hand on all ids and

```
    $.[*].siteActivity.[categoryId]
```

for category ids. 
Next, I want to use the above values and send them as parameters in request body.
Currently, I am able to extract only one id with

```
   $.[0].id
```

and then assigning it to variable "id" and using the following in request body

```
 {"ids":[{"id":"${id}"}]}
```

but I want to be able to send

```
 {"ids":[{"id":"${id}"},{"id":"${id2}"}....]}
```

There is no limit on how many ids can be there, so I cannot hardcode and need something dynamic to do the aggregation. What kind of processor can help me here? Please add some example if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should be able to use [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) for building the request.

Given your sample data your `$.[*].id` JSONPath Expression should return the following values:

```
id=[3767,118156]
id_1=3767
id_2=118156
```

So basically you need to:

1. Determine "id" count
2. Populate dynamic JSON Object to send
3. Store it to JMeter variable for later use

In order to do so add a Beanshell PostProcessor **after** JSONPath Extractor and put the following code into its "Script" area

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject; // necessary imports

JSONObject data2Send = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(); // instantiate JSON-related classes

int idCount = vars.get("id").split(",").length; // get "id" variables count

for (int i = 1; i <= idCount; i++) { // for each "id" variable
    JSONObject id = new JSONObject(); // construct a new JSON Object
    id.put("id", vars.get("id_" + i));// with name "id" and value id_X 
    array.add(id);  // add object to array
} 

data2Send.put("ids",array); // add array to "ids" JSON Object
vars.put("myJSON", data2Send.toString()); // store value as "myJSON" variable
```

You can refer to your `{"ids":[{"id":"3767"},{"id":"118156"}]}` data as `${myJSON}` where required.

The approach will play for any number of "id" variables.

References:

- [Welcome to Json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)
- [How to use json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html)
- [Json-lib JavaDoc](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/index.html)
- [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)